# Django// How to display complex depth data in template

Tags: python, django

Django 2.2//

python 3.6//

---

I have a context created with a combination of 'list' and 'dictionary'.

The data structure is shown below.

```
{ 
   "Mike":[ 
      { 
         "month":"2020-02",
         "consult_counts_total":2,
         "consult_counts_total_uid":2
      },
      { 
         "month":"2020-01",
         "consult_counts_total":4,
         "consult_counts_total_uid":7
      },
      { 
         "month":"2019-12",
         "consult_counts_total":6,
         "consult_counts_total_uid":1
      }
   ],
   "Jaden":[ 
      { 
         "month":"2020-02",
         "consult_counts_total":8,
         "consult_counts_total_uid":12
      },
      { 
         "month":"2020-01",
         "consult_counts_total":23,
         "consult_counts_total_uid":11
      },
      { 
         "month":"2019-12",
         "consult_counts_total":2,
         "consult_counts_total_uid":19
      }
   ],
   "Sarah":[ 
      { 
         "month":"2020-02",
         "consult_counts_total":2,
         "consult_counts_total_uid":2
      },
      { 
         "month":"2020-01",
         "consult_counts_total":4,
         "consult_counts_total_uid":7
      },
      { 
         "month":"2019-12",
         "consult_counts_total":6,
         "consult_counts_total_uid":1
      }
   ],
   "John":[ 
      { 
         "month":"2020-02",
         "consult_counts_total":1,
         "consult_counts_total_uid":0
      },
      { 
         "month":"2020-01",
         "consult_counts_total":2,
         "consult_counts_total_uid":7
      },
      { 
         "month":"2019-12",
         "consult_counts_total":5,
         "consult_counts_total_uid":1
      }
   ]
}
```

I'm trying to display this data through a loop in template.

First I'v tried. It shows nice result.

```
{% for foo in context_data %}
    <p>{{ foo }}</p>
{% endfor %}


# result

Mike
Jaden
Sarah
John
```

But I can't get more depth data.

For example, I want to get Mike's all months (2020-02, 2020-01, 2019-12)

Second tried..

```
{% for foo in context_data %}
    <p class="big">This is {{ foo }}'s months.</p>
    {% for foo2 in foo %}
        <p class="small">{{ foo2.months }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}

# but it's showing nothing
```

Third tried..

```
{% for foo in context_data %}
    <p class="big">This is {{ foo }}'s months.</p>
    {% for foo2 in foo %}
        <p class="small">{{ foo2 }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
    <br>
{% endfor %}

# result
This is Mike's months.
M
i
k
e
```

Third code looping "Mike" string.. not Mike's under data.

I expect showing like this.

```
This is Mike's months.
2020-02
2020-01
2019-12

This is Jaden's months.
2020-02
2020-01
2019-12

This is Sarah's months.
2020-02
2020-01
2019-12

This is John's months.
2020-02
2020-01
2019-12
```

How can I this?

Comment: What is the `context_data` that you are passing? The `dict`, not the `json` data info.

Comment: You have `{{ foo2.months }}` in your second try, is that a typo? it should just be `month`

Comment: @chrisbyte When I write a question here, I think I made a typo. "month" is correct.

Comment: @Felipe I made this data with list and dic in the views.py and rendering to the template. so it isn't json data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are iterating only keys, should iterate values using **items** to dictionary.

```
{% for key, values in context_data.items %}
    <p class="big">This is {{ key }}'s months.</p>
    {% for foo2 in values %}
        <p class="small">{{ foo2.month }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
    <br>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Saisiva A // You let me know exactly what I didn't know.
The person name is getting well in the way you told me. But I can't get the data from "Values", probably because it's one step deeper into "List". How should this be solved?

Comment: Oh oh. Works fine. Thank you.